# Can't reach my server from itself using external IP

Tags: networking, nat

I'm not a big expert in setting up networks, please help.

What I have?

1. I have a server running a server on port 80, on the local network I
   can reach it at `https://192.168.1.100:80`
2. I have an external fixed IP for access from outside, let it be `88.77.66.55`.
3. I have a router on which I have configured port forwarding from `192.168.1.100:80` to `8080`.

As a result, I can reach my service using external IP `https://88.77.66.55:8080`, **but when when I try to access directly from this server i get network error, host not reachable.**

From other devices this server is available from internal (192.168.1.100:80) and external (`88.77.66.55:8080`) address fine. From this server, it is accessible to itself only via the local network (`192.168.1.100:80`). **Why and how to setup it?**

Router settings:
[image]
Chrome error:
[image]

Comment: You are trying to do hairpin routing, but that wastes router resources and uses the bandwidth of your routers LAN link. You should set your internal DNS to return the local address instead of the external address. That way, you keep local traffic local and do not involve the router.